# HP EliteBook 2540p - Firmware Update Assistance for Integrated Module and Hard Drive

Tags: drivers, 22.04, hp, firmware

I'm seeking assistance with updating firmware on my HP EliteBook 2540p running Ubuntu  22.04

Hardware Information:

```
HP Integrated Module:
    Device ID: c0170efdf195b8590000fa21474253c0d97e7335
    Current Version: 3.6
    Vendor: Broadcom Corp (USB:0x03F0)
Toshiba Hard Drive:
    Model: MK1633GSG
    Current Version: QS001C
```

Attempted Steps:

```
I have used the fwupdmgr tool, but it did not find any available updates.
Can anyone provide guidance on the recommended approach to update the firmware for these specific components on my HP EliteBook 2540p with Ubuntu?
Are there any official resources or tools available from HP or Toshiba for these updates?

I have already checked the HP and Toshiba websites for support information but haven't found specific instructions for my model and Ubuntu.
```

Comment: On the HP, isn't there an option to upgrade the firmware in the system? Whilst booting the PC, constantly press the `Esc` key to enter the BIOS and select it from there.